# Vuetify v-data-table fixed-header not working

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I using Vuetify `v-data-table` component, and set `fixed-header` property, but table header is scrolling together with table body. I using latest Chrome. Can any body tell how to fix that behavior to work correctly?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to specify the height attribute. It is even possible to pass in height="100%" and it will work.

```
<v-data-table
      height="400"
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      fixed-header
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
    >
</v-data-table>
```

https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/gOpzBmQ

Comment: yes, I got it - I forget to set a height of table, thanks!

Comment: This works, but I find it troublesome to have to set a specific height, when I want the data table to basically take up the entirety of the screen.

Comment: If you are using a v-simple-table instead of a v-data-table, you should also make sure that you are using th tags in the header instead of regular td tags, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Using Vuetify v2.5.7 and setting `height="100%"` does not work for me. Setting an explicit height does, however.

Comment: @ellisdod can you update your answer,: `height="100%"` doesn't work :( I tried to change it with your codepen and it really doesn't.

Answer (score 21):

For me `height="100%"` did not work, and setting the height in pixels also wasn't an option for me since I wanted the table to consume the whole page height, so I ended up with `height="100vh"`.

```html
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    disable-pagination
    fixed-header
    hide-default-footer
    dark
    height="100vh">
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution if you don't want a fixed height and expect your table to take all the space available.

Just use flexbox with `flex-grow: 1; overflow: hidden;` on the container, and set a class to the table itself with `display: flex; flex-grow: 1;`

Here is the codepen demo : https://codepen.io/esquilax76/pen/gOoGyPb

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

This one works well for me. It is using section that is very cool to work with.

```html
    <section class="view">
      <v-card class="card-top">
        Header
      </v-card>
      <v-card class="table-container">
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          fixed-header
          hide-default-footer
          disable-pagination
          class="flex-table"
        />
      </v-card>
    </section>
```

https://codepen.io/esquilax76/pen/gOoGyPb

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, we  have to calculate the pixels of the elements that are above the v-data-table, in my case it was the header and subtract it from 100vh, something like this calc(100vh - 245px)

```
       <v-data-table
         :headers="headers"
         :items="orders"
         :loading="isLoading"
         fixed-header
         height="calc(100vh - 245px)"
       >
```